# ionic cordova run android fails

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

i am trying to run my app using ionic cordova run android but it is failing.

Please help.

Thanks.

here is my exception

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\My Drive\Demo\Mobile App\IonicApps\TestApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 40
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > com/google/gson/JsonParseException
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
(node:11680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\My Drive\Demo\Mobile App\IonicApps\TestApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 40
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > com/google/gson/JsonParseException
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\My Drive\Demo\Mobile App\IonicApps\TestApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:11680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11680) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: did you try **./gradlew clean**??

Comment: how do i have to use this command it shows ./gradlew is not a command

Comment: This command fixes all of the gradle error and removes the error. Yes you should try this command in platforms/android folder where gradlew exists.

Comment: i tried this but getting the same error. C:\My Drive\Demo\Mobile App\IonicApps\TestApp\platforms\android>gradlew clean
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\My Drive\Demo\Mobile App\IonicApps\TestApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 40

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> com/google/gson/JsonParseException

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out such trouble by doing this following trick.

First of all, keep your global npm libs - **npm**, **ionic-cli**, **cordova** *up-to-date*.

```
$ node --version
v8.12.0
$ npm --version
6.4.1
$ ionic --version
4.1.2
$ cordova --version
8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)
```

Then, you should install(*downgrade*, perhaps) the platform **cordova-android@6.3.0** to your cordova project. For this aim, force to install plugin **cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0**.

After adding platform, create a file so-called **build-extras.gradle** with the following content to overcome **cordova-android@6.3.0** issue.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```

Put this file into **platforms/android** folder.

Later on, try `cordova build android` once more!

**PS:** **cordova-android@6.4+** would cause irritating failures.